# How do you enable curl on a docker container?

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, curl, php-curl

I'm about at my wits end with this, have tried so many different things I've lost track.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM wordpress:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install curl
RUN docker-php-ext-enable curl
```

Here is my compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    # We use a mariadb image which supports both amd64 & arm64 architecture
    #image: mariadb:10.6.4-focal
    # If you really want to use MySQL, uncomment the following line
    image: mysql:8.0.27
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060
  wordpress:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - $PWD/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Here is the list of extensions in php.ini that is referenced in that compose file. If you need to see the full thing, I'll have to find another way to send it because it's well over the limit of characters.

```
; Notes for Windows environments :
;
; - Many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) or ext/ (PHP 5+)
;   extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5+).
;   Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.
;
;extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=oci8_19  ; Use with Oracle Database 19 Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

I can SSH into the container and confirm that curl is installed and working, I can confirm that that php.ini is mapped to and replacing the php.ini-development in the container as well. Still, when I call curl_init() in one of my files I get "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init()....."

I have run out of things to try, any other options?

Comment: Call `phpinfo()` from PHP. That will tell you the PHP.INI file in use, and  whether `curl` is actually installed.

Comment: Did this, "cURL support: enabled"
"cURL Information: 7.74.0"

Comment: Your dockerfile isn't used anywhere in your compose file.

Comment: @Zeitounator It makes no difference but I updated it to use the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I spun up a new container and it worked just fine with the above files. I must have changed a setting accidentally on the original containers or something.